# Using declaration for specific overloaded function based on access specifier

Tags: c++

This code

```
struct Foo{
    void f(){
        f(0);
    }
private:
    void f(int){}
};

struct Bar : private Foo{
    using Foo::f;
};

int main() {
    Bar b;
    b.f();
}
```

[fails to compile](http://ideone.com/MzOmoA) because `Foo::f(int)` is `private`. I am not interested in `Foo::f(int)`, I just want `Foo::f()` which is `public`, so I feel there should be a way to do it.

There are some workarounds I can think of:

1. rename `Foo::f(int)` to `Foo::p_f(int)`, but that is redundant and disallows overload resolution for `f`
2. implementing `Bar::foo(){Foo::f();}` becomes a lot of copy/paste for multiple `public` `f`s
3. inheriting `public`ly from `Foo` which invites UB since `~Foo()` is not `virtual` (and is not supposed to be)
4. making all `f`s `public` makes it too easy to accidentally break `Foo` and `Bar`

Is there a way to say `using public Foo::f;`? Or use one of the workarounds without the associated downsides?

Comment: Not having a virtual destructor in the base class is not automatically UB. It's only UB if you have a pointer (or reference) to the base-class which is actually pointing to (or referencing) a child-class instance, and you destroy the instance. In the (admittedly simple) code you show there is no UB with public inheritance.

Comment: Having these have the same name is a bad idea actually and the reason why it's bad includes this using-declaration mess. I recommend reading about the "non virtual interface" which also helps to reduce this mess.

Comment: Why not make `Foo::f(int)` a protected method? Any code that uses `Bar` or `Foo` will still only be able to access `Foo::f(void)`, so the interface is consistent.

Comment: An alternative solution would be to derive `Foo` from another class, let's say `FooInterface`. Then in `Bar` you can say `using FooInterface::f`.

Comment: @Archimaredes [Doesn't seem to work](http://ideone.com/yaj0Ha). If I make `Foo::f(int)` protected then `Bar::f(int)` becomes `public`.

Comment: your point 1. is unclear: why would any user care about the how the private helper `f(int)` is named?

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb I don't see how a non-virtual interface would help me here. I don't want/need any `virtual` functions.

Comment: @TemplateRex Because every overload of `f` conceptually does the same thing. `f` is recursive and the public versions just apply sane start values. Renaming would be possible, but doing manual overload resolution is not fun. I suppose one could delegate to a private version that gives sane start values.

Comment: If you are modeling a is-implemented relationship, and since you are using private inheritance you are, I think you missed one alternative: use composition. In general composition is to be favored over inheritance, except when modeling strict is-a relationship as by the Liskov principle.

Answer (score 0):

If your `f(int)` is supposed to be `private`, and will never ever be part of a public API, then **you should not care about renaming it to `fimpl`**:

```
struct Foo{
    void f(){
        fimpl(0);
    }
private:
    void fimpl(int){}
};
```

If, on the other hand, `f(int)` is the general version of a public API, and you also want a single convenience wrapper with a particular value, you can use provide a default argument and make `f(int)` a `public` member.

```
struct Foo{
    void f(int = 0){}
};
```

Finally, if you want several named functions that provide certain integer values, then I'd suggest renaming those wrappers

```
struct Foo{
    void f(int) {} // general interface
    void sensible_name1() { f(0); }
    void sensible_name2() { f(1); } // etc.
}
```

Comment: This is wrong. ["In a *using-declaration* that does not name a constructor, all members of the set of introduced declarations shall be accessible. \[...\] In particular, if a derived class uses a *using-declaration* to access a member of a base class, the member name shall be accessible. If the name is that of an overloaded member function, then all functions named shall be accessible."](http://eel.is/c++draft/namespace.udecl#17)

Comment: @T.C. interestingly the wording contains a slight ambiguity. Consider the case where `Bar` has a `void f(int) = delete;`. Then because there would be a conflict, the spec says that the name corresponding to the `Foo::f(int)` overload is *not* introduced. The first rule says that no access violation for this name is given. But the last sentence of overloaded functions says that an access violations for all names must be given potentially. I don't think this is intended: If `void f(int)` in Foo would be the only constituent of the name `f`, the spec requires to not give an access violation then.

Comment: `f(int =0)` essentially makes `f(int)` `public`, which is not a good option. I suppose I'll have to manually tag `private` functions.

Answer (score -3):

Your code currently derives `Bar` from `Foo` as `private`. Due to that, `Foo::f()` is a *private method* in `Bar`. You can change that by changing your class declaration to `struct Bar: public Foo`.

For some background, see the Section on "Private Inheritance" under [Derived Classes](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/derived_class). Specifically, the section explains that:

> [w]hen a class uses private member access specifier to derive from a base, all public and protected members of the base class are accessible as private members of the derived class (private members of the base are never accessible unless friended).